# None https websites access issue under the same IP

Tags: https

I found a weird issue today for none-https website. I have 5 sites hosted on the same IP. Only 1 website has ssl enabled, name it Site A.

However, When I access https version of none-https sites like Site B, the content is a direct copy of Site A.

How to solve this?

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to be able to answer.  I suggest contacting your hosting service.

Comment: What kind of information to be added? Hosting provider can't help on this coz it is not a managed service

Comment: What happens when you activate SSL on other sites?  Why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: The sites without ssl are not important so we don't use and activate ssl on them.

Comment: Presumably you first get a browser security warning that the security certificate is invalid (that you must click through/accept)? It sounds like you perhaps have the vhost configs defined in the "wrong" order (or you don't have a "default" config) and it's defaulting to the first defined vhost for port 443?

Comment: how to fix this on CentOS? P.S there is default vhost entry for the control panel.

Comment: The solution should not be specific to CentOS. This is an Apache question? Do you get a SSL cert browser warning (as I asked above)? You would need to add your server config (vHosts) to your question and request that your question be reopened.